# Stain on internal wall

Tags: walls, trim, stain

Hi there I have a stain on internal wall under the window. Only in living room. Brick wall. Stain has been painted but always came back. House has been insulated (external wall) last year but the problem still exists. No leak on anything visibly.not sure what to do.
[stain on wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmXPF.jpg)

[image: stain on wall]

Comment: You say internal wall. Do you mean "inside of an exterior wall" or do you mean "a wall that is completely inside the house on both sides?" that's not clear from what you have written. Please [edit] the question to clarify that.

Comment: Some stains might need a stain hider/killer primer or they show up if just painted over.  Adding the paint type and if primer was used into the question will help.

Comment: It's either the stain coming through the paint, or the leak simply hasn't been fixed and more water is coming in.

Comment: Insulated last year? There's a process for blowing in insulation from exterior side of the walls, but assuming it was insulated by removing the sheetrock, then the stain has only showed up on the new sheetrock? Or was this a familiar pattern before the addition of insulation?

Answer (score 2):

Apply an oil based primer like Kilz, and then paint it again. Water based paints cannot be used over oil based paints, but oil based primer is different: You can use water based paint over it.